# How to do Multiple select option using php?

Tags: php

I like do multiple select option using PHP , but i am unable to do multiple select.
this is my code

```
 <?
    include_once("common.php");
     $iCompanyId = isset($_REQUEST['company'])?$_REQUEST['company']:'';
     $iDriverId = isset($_REQUEST['iDriverId'])?$_REQUEST['iDriverId']:''; 
    $selected = "selected"; 
    if($iCompanyId != '')
    {
        $sql = "select * from register_driver where iCompanyId = '".$iCompanyId."' and eStatus != 'Deleted'";
        $db_model = $obj->MySQLSelect($sql);
        $cont = '';
        $cont .= '<select multiple class="validate[required] form-control" id="iDriverId1" name="iDriverId">';
        $cont .= '<option value="">CHOOSE DRIVER </option>';
        for($i=0;$i<count($db_model);$i++){
            if($db_model[$i]['iDriverId'] == $iDriverId)

                $cont .= '<option value="'.$db_model[$i]['iDriverId'].'"  '.$selected.'>'.$db_model[$i]['vName'].' '.$db_model[$i]['vLastName'].'</option>'; 
            else
                 $cont .= '<option value="'.$db_model[$i]['iDriverId'].'">'.$db_model[$i]['vName'].' '.$db_model[$i]['vLastName'].'</option>'; 
        }
        $cont .= '</select>';

        echo $cont; exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, you are “unable to”? Please go read [ask].

Comment: You will want to use a name like `name="iDriverId[]"` for the field, the square brackets make PHP create an array out of the submitted values. If you don’t, you will only get the value of the last selected option.

Comment: Again, please go read [ask]. You need to give us a proper problem description - “unable to” is not one, and giving such small pieces of secondary info in comments as you are trying to do right now, is not very helpful either. _Read it_, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use '**selected** **Attribute**'  like

```
if(condition) { <option value="" selected> test</option>
```